# Regex that only matches when 4 specific words were found

Tags: javascript, regex

As the title says, I need a Regex to check if a string has this four words (Update, Rollback, Skip, Not Now) and only return them if all of them are present, if not it doesn’t return anything.

Here is an example:
`{"Update":"iVBORw0KGgo","Rollback":"iVBORw0KGgo","Skip":"iVBORw0KGgo","Not Now":"iVBORw0KGgo"}`

> In this case, it should return [Update, Rollback, Skip, Not Now]

`{"Update":"iVBORw0KGgo","Skip":"iVBORw0KGgo","Not Now":"iVBORw0KGgo"}`

> In this case, it shouldn’t return any value

I tried to create one by myself but my knowledge of Regex is very basic:
`(Update|Rollback|Skip|Not Now)`

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT**

I noticed that Regex might not be the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Does the order matter of the words matter?

Comment: No, the order doesn't matter it just needs to match anything if 4 were found, and nothing if 1 is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
^(?=.*"Update"\s*:)(?=.*"Rollback"\s*:)(?=.*"Skip"\s*:)(?=.*"Not Now"\s*:)
```

`(?=...)` means that if you lookahead, you find this pattern.

So an empty match will return as soon as we find all these 4 patterns.

[demo](https://regexr.com/6767q)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to regex, you can use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse the string into an object and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the properties:

```js
const str = `{"Update":"iVBORw0KGgo","Rollback":"iVBORw0KGgo","Skip":"iVBORw0KGgo","Not Now":"iVBORw0KGgo"}`;

const keys = Object.keys(JSON.parse(str))

const result = keys.sort().toString() == "Not Now,Rollback,Skip,Update" ? keys : "";

console.log(result)
```

Comment: The question does not state that all the four "keys" must be present in the string, so perhaps something like (pseudocode) `(["Update", "Rollback", "Skip", "Not Now"] - keys).empty? ?....`

Comment: @CarySwoveland I might be wrong, but my interpretation of the OP's post is that he is. *"only return them if all of them are present, if not it doesn’t return anything."*

Comment: Yes, but will not `keys.sort().toString() == "Not Now,Rollback,Skip,Update"` fail if the hash has those four keys but other keys as well? I don't know Javascript but your statment seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

While regex is clearly not a good tool for the job,
you can do something like this:

```
re.match("(?=.*Update.*)(?=.*Skip.*)",string)
```

`"(?=WORD)"` matches if the expression follows, but doesn't consume any of the string.

Of course, complete the regex by all  4 words that you want similarly.

Also notice that regex by itself doesn't return anything. You need to code for this.

Comment: The tag is Javascript, not Python. In `(?=.*Update.*)` should be `(?=.*"Update")` (the trailing `.*` has no effect).